# OnModeChanging Event of FormView fired and Code executed but result not shown

Tags: asp.net

When FormView OnModeChangingEVent fired I want to Enable/disable Textbox depending on weather the checkbox checked or not.
But when i click Edit button OnModeChanging Event fired and code shown below exccuted but the result is not displayed after the Mode is changed(i.e Textbox 1 is not disabled when Checkbox1 is checked  ). Can any one help me out?

```
<asp:formview  ID="FormView1" OnModeChanging="FormView1_ModeChanging" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:formview>


protected void FormView1_ModeChanging(object sender, FormViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.NewMode)
    {
        case FormViewMode.Edit:
            TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)FormView1.FindControl("TextBox1");
            CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)FormView1.FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                TextBox1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Enabled = true;
            }

          break;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Are those typo's or are you purposefully just disabling the checkbox if it's checked and enabling it if it's unchecked?

Comment: I want to disable purposefully, user only enter data either in textbox or check checkbox and can not enter both

Comment: You want to disable the **Checkbox**??  That's not what your question seems to indicate.

Comment: I mean sir I want to disable textbox only when checkbox is checked .if checkbox is unchecked textbox will be Enabled

Comment: So is your **post** in error, or is your actual **code** in error?

Comment: The value of checkbox is cloned from database. thank you sir

Comment: I don't know what that means.  The code in your post has you disabling the **checkbox** and not the **textbox**: `CheckBox1.Enabled = false;`  This is contrary to what you are saying you want to do, so I'm trying to figure out whether your _post_ has a typo, or you actually did this wrong in your code (which might be the root of your problem).  Please re-read your question **carefully**.

Comment: I didn't get exception. the code executed fine but Textbox is not disabled when checkbox is checked after mode is changed to edit. it is confusing me

Comment: I didn't say anything about an exception...

Comment: I am sorry that is by mistake,I edited it.Thank you sir.

Comment: Please sir I need your help to solve this problem

Comment: @BireMan Are you sure the execution goes into your if statement? And do you have any other code elsewhere, in another event handler which may be enabling it again...

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes sir I am sure i debuged it. I also tried it by writing the above code in a new webform to make sure if there is an influence of other code but it turns out the same,thanks